# Change Detector Tree

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

We have an application where we *need* to dettach from the ChangeDetector and everything works so far.

This is our current component structure:

```
AComponent (Normal Component, Attached)
   BComponent (Detaches from ChangeDetector)
      CComponent (Detached, because the parent is detached)
         DComponent (Should Reattach)
            MatInput or whatever
      CComponent (Detached)
      ...
```

We need to reattach the DComponent tho, because it should contain some material controls that require the change detection. I've tried manually calling `.reattach` on a `ChangeDetectorRef`, which should not even be necessary according to the doc - but the component won't attach anyways.

I've tried around and added a simple button / counter that should be detected - but it won't update the counter label.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-d',
  template: ` <button (click)="add()">Add 1</button>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Some Label {{ counter }}</mat-label>

      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4]" [value]="item">
          {{ item }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>`
})
export default class DComponent implements OnInit {
  counter = 1;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeDetector.reattach();
  }

  add() {
    this.counter += 1;
  }
}
```

I assume that I am outside of the change detection tree because of the parent element (BComponent) that detached itself from the change detector - Is there a way to reattach DComponent, without attaching BComponent?

Thank you!